# Why does my Google Analytics data change every export?

Tags: google-analytics

I receive several reports from Google Analytics on website logins every week. Historically, the data in the previous week's report and the latest report is always the same. Lately, I noticed that the data changes every week. For example, the data in the July 9 report is different in the July 15 report. Why is that?

**JULY 9 REPORT**

```
Row Labels  A   B   C   D   Grand Total
7/1/2023    6   0   0   11  17
7/2/2023    11  0   6   22  39
7/3/2023    22  11  11  22  66
7/4/2023    22  22  6   22  72
7/5/2023    28  17  34  34  113
7/6/2023    11  11  28  28  78
7/7/2023    6   22  28  28  84
7/8/2023    6   0   0   6   12
```

**JULY 15 REPORT**

```
Row Labels  A   B   C   D   Grand Total
7/1/2023    7   5   4   3   19
7/2/2023    19  12  13  12  56
7/3/2023    19  23  11  13  66
7/4/2023    22  19  17  16  74
7/5/2023    22  24  40  30  116
7/6/2023    13  16  35  24  88
7/7/2023    16  18  35  17  86
7/8/2023    16  11  21  10  58
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't have access to our company's Google Analytics account and I'm not a Google Analytics expert.

Comment: what metric are we talking about?

Comment: Website logins @BNazaruk

Comment: just simple hit-level dimensions then? To debug it properly, you need to know what dimensions and how are being exported. If you're not exposed to that, you need to pass this issue onto the people doing ETL, or analysts who actually work with GA.